# Is there a way to display data in graph view when using group_operator=False?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I would like to display field data in graph view even when field has set group_operator=False. Even if no group_by is used in view I still get no data in graph view.

Is there any way to achieve it? (custom report model, read_group or fields_view_get, ...)